# Would Database connection leak in one app affect others in the server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-leaks, jboss, jboss6.x

I am using a jboss EAP 6.1 server and there are around 20 applications i have hosted on it. All the 20 uses distinct databases located in 5 database servers.

If there is a connection leak in one application, would that connection affect the other applications?

The below is the error that i get when i am testing the connection of the database of a specific application. The strange thing is, it says it is caused by a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
06:31:22,981 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:8809-3) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:288)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:246)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:788)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:344)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:404)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:372)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
    at com.mycomp.availability.DataSourceAvailTest.test(DataSourceAvailTest.java:167) [classes:]
    at org.apache.jsp.checkavail_jsp._jspService(checkavail_jsp.java:191)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:407) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.3.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:490) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:562)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:259)
```

Comment: What URL you are using? Please add datasource configuration from standalone.xml

Comment: @Neeraj : i do not have access to the datasource configuration. Do you think this is happening because of a misconfiguration in the database JNDI?

Comment: Yes, because exception is coming when trying to get driverkey from configured <connection-url> in datasource. It is trying to get index of second ":" in <connection-url> but throwing exception because it is not defined correctly.

Comment: okay.. i will try to get a hold of the config file. But can you tell me how you know it is looking for the second ":"? and i am trying to find out the location of the jar that contains the `LocalMangedConnectionFactory` class.

Comment: I checked source code of `LocalMangedConnectionFactory` This class is in `jdbcadapters`. you can find it in `{JBOSS_HOME}\modules\org\jboss\ironjacamar`

Comment: I was trying to find that path for hours now... thank you so much... btw in my windows it was in the location `{JBOSS_HOME}\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\ironjacamar`. i saw the code too.. with the assumption that the connection URL is set properly for instance like this, `jdbc:sqlserver://servername` why is it searching for the `:` at or after the index `6`..?

Comment: It is trying to get driver key, like in your case it will take `jdbc:sqlserver` as key and will load driver from cache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59175/discussion-between-black-panther-and-neeraj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception is coming when trying to get driverkey from configured `<connection-url>` in datasource. It is trying to get index of second `":"` in `<connection-url>` but throwing exception because it is not defined correctly.

You can check source code of `LocalMangedConnectionFactory` This class is in `jdbcadapters`. you can find it in `{JBOSS_HOME}\modules\org\jboss\ironjacamar`

It is trying to get driver key, like in your case it will take `jdbc:sqlserver` as key and will load driver from cache.